# how to deal with Special characters in stock symbol to download adj.close in R software

Tags: r

I need download VIX historical data with R software.and then pick the adjusted price
I run the code

```
getSymbols("^VIX", from="2016-01-01" , to="2018-01-01")
```

and download the data but when I want to pick only adjusted value with the code

```
^VIX <-^VIX$^VIX.Adjusted
```

I got this error:

> Error: unexpected '^' in "^"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) ls()** Your `getSymbols` command in the question is correct but the name which is used to store the data is slightly different than the Yahoo ticker symbol. Run `ls()` to see the names of the objects in your workspace and you will see that the name under which the data is stored is `VIX` and not `^VIX`.

To get the adjusted close use `Ad`

```
vix.ad <- Ad(VIX)
```

**2) auto.assign=** Another way to do this is to use the `auto.assign=`argument like this.  In this case we don't need to know the name since it returns the object rather than setting it in the global environment,

```
vix.ad <- Ad(getSymbols("^VIX", auto.assign = FALSE))
```

**3) env=** A different way to do this is to create an environment `e` to hold the data.  The only object there is the one wanted.  Since there is only one object in `e` using `eapply` to apply `Ad` to every object in `e` will apply it to the object of interest without knowing its name.  `eapply` returns a list with one element per object in `e` but since `e` has only one object we can use [[1]] to get this single component and put it in an object using whatever name you choose.  Below we called it `vix.ad`.  Remove `e` at the end just in case this is repeated with another symbol since we wouldn't want to have two objects in `e`.

```
getSymbols("^VIX", env = e <- new.env())
vix.ad <- eapply(e, Ad)[[1]]
rm(e) # don't need e any more
```

Suggest you review all the quantmod help files: `help(package = "quantmod")`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(magrittr)

tq_get("^VIX", 
       from = "2016-01-01",
       to = "2018-01-01") %>% 
  select(adjusted) %$% 
  mean(adjusted)

[1] 13.46264
```

Comment: Thank you. NOw how can I call it? For example how can I take mean of this series?

Comment: @NedaFathi What do you mean?

Comment: By run the code I got this error:                                                               
         mean(adjusted)
Error in mean(adjusted) : object 'adjusted' not found
>   var(adjusted)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'adjusted' not found. I want to call the adjusted price to do some thing more with it. But when I call it as adjusted I face error like above.